# Getting error convert Hex value to RGB in Swift

Tags: swift

```
code:

    vwloginView.backgroundColor =  UIColorFromRGB(52DBD1)

        func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
            return UIColor(
                red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
                green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
                blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
                alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
            )
        }
```

The above what i tried to convert to Hex value to RGB in swift.It shows error as  "Expected a digit after integer literal prefix".What it is meaning?What change done to solve this problem?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`52DBD1` is an hexadecimal number, so you have to tell that to the compiler, by prefixing it with `0x`:

```
UIColorFromRGB(0x52DBD1)
```

Suggested reading: [Numeric Literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_474)